# How can I subset based on multiple criteria?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of this nature:

```
id year levels
A  1967 cat
B  1965 dog
C  1980 cat
A  1989 dog
B  1990 mouse
C  2010 pig
```

And I want to subset once using these criteria at the same time:

```
1. id = A
2. year > 1980
3. levels = dog
```

I know how to do subset(df, year>1980) but don't know how to combine these criteria.

When I do this,

```
sub<-subset(all,year>1980 & id == 'A' & levels == 'dog')
```

I get an empty dataframe

Comment: I get one row with your `subset` call.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I had a typo in my column name. :-( Darn.

Comment: Please remove this question then. Thanks.

Comment: works for me too (one row).

Comment: Because it has an answer, I can't delete it.

Comment: I have flagged it for the moderator to delete.

Answer (score 4):

you  can try:

```
df[df$id == "A" & df$year > 1980 & df$levels == "dog",]
```